# Ofstream rejects input with parameters

Tags: c++, output, ofstream

i am working for school project and i have to write some lines to a txt file. Nothing unusual but here comes the problem. When i try to input output file name through parameters in function it says that there is no matching function for call. Let me show you my code:

```
bool save(vector<City*> city, string output){
   ofstream dat(output); // ... here comes the problem
}
```

I would be very happy if someone would know what is problem here and how to make it work. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either to enable the `-std=c++11` compiler option, or use `ofstream dat(output.c_str());`

See the reference documentation of the available [`std::ofstream` constuctors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

Comment: ofstream dat(output.c_str()); <br/> that helped thanks :)

Comment: @lucian24 I think both options should work equally well.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to enable c++11 in eclipse so i just used second one

Comment: @lucian24 You can enable that in the projects c++ build options.

Comment: Thanks i wil try to find it